# I am trying to make a rock, paper, scissors game on c++ and need some advice

Tags: c++

These are the instructions:

> Implement a C++ console application that simulates a
>   Rock-Paper-Scissor game against the computer. When played between two
>   people, each person picks one of three options (usually shown by hand
>   gesture) at the same time, and a winner is determined. In the game,
>   Rock beats Scissors, Scissors beats Paper, and Paper beats Rock. The
>   program should randomly choose one of the three options (without
>   revealing it), then ask for user input (choice of Rock, Paper or
>   Scissor), and finally compare with user’s choice. At that point, the
>   program reveals both choices and prints a statement indicating if the
>   user won, the computer won, or it was a tie. Application should keep
>   track of the current score (i.e. the number of user wins, losses, and
>   ties) and update the screen after every play. User should be prompted
>   after every game if they want to continue playing. At the beginning of
>   the game the program should also ask the user for their name and
>   display this name when showing the score. You do not need to use any
>   user-defined functions for this assignment but you can add whatever
>   you like so long as the criteria at the end of this document has been
>   met. No bonus marks will be given, however.
>
> In addition to the requirements above, as part of this assignment you
>   are to implement storing of game data into a text file. Game should
>   always ask for a username (it has to be at least 8 characters) and
>   store game results in a file with the same name as the username
>   (username.txt). If the user has played the game before, the data
>   should be read from the file and displayed on screen before starting a
>   new game. At the end of the game the statistics should be saved on the
>   same file.  Game should not allow for same usernames unless it is the
>   same user. This means that the game should check for existing
>   usernames and prompt the new user for further authentication if
>   needed. This would also guarantee that every user will have a unique
>   game data statistics stored and not overridden by another user with
>   the same username.

And this is what I've come up with so far:

```
#include "pch.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string PlayerUsername;

    string Playerinput;

    string Winner;

    int Wins;

    int Draws;

    int Losses;

    int RNG = rand() % 3 + 1;

    std::cout << "Print your name.\n";
    cin >> PlayerUsername;

    std::cout << "Hello >>PlayerUsername>>. This is a rock, paper, scissors game. The rules are as follows: rock beats scissors, paper beats rock, and scissors beats paper. The computer will randomly pick one of the three. Print n1 for rock, print n2 for paper, print n3 for scissors. Input your choice if you wish to play. Otherwise close the program.\n";

    if (RNG == "1" && Playerinput == "rock") { std::cout << "The outcome of this game was a tie." << endl; }

    else if (RNG == "2" && Playerinput == "scissors") { std::cout << "Computer wins." << endl; }

    else if (RNG == "2" && Playerinput == "paper") { std::cout << "The outcome of this game was a tie." << endl; }

    else if (RNG == "2" && Playerinput == "rock") { std::cout << "Computer wins." << endl; }

    else if (RNG == "3" && Playerinput == "scissors") { std::cout << "The outcome of this game was a tie." << endl; }

    else if (RNG == "3" && Playerinput == "paper") { std::cout << "Computer wins." << endl; }

    else {
        std::cout << "You win." << endl;
    }
    cin >> Playerinput
}
```

Note: The code is not compiling.
Errors: 
 * The system cannot find the file specified is the popup that I get from visual studio community.
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  Rock, Paper, Scissors   C:\Users\FULVIO\source\repos\Rock, Paper, Scissors\Rock, Paper, Scissors.cpp    18
Error (active)  E0042   operand types are incompatible ("int" and "const char *")   Rock, Paper, Scissors   C:\Users\FULVIO\source\repos\Rock, Paper, Scissors\Rock, Paper, Scissors.cpp    21
Error (active)  E0042   operand types are incompatible ("int" and "const char *")   Rock, Paper, Scissors   C:\Users\FULVIO\source\repos\Rock, Paper, Scissors\Rock, Paper, Scissors.cpp    23
Error (active)  E0042   operand types are incompatible ("int" and "const char *")   Rock, Paper, Scissors   C:\Users\FULVIO\source\repos\Rock, Paper, Scissors\Rock, Paper, Scissors.cpp    25
Error (active)  E0042   operand types are incompatible ("int" and "const char *")   Rock, Paper, Scissors   C:\Users\FULVIO\source\repos\Rock, Paper, Scissors\Rock, Paper, Scissors.cpp    27
Error (active)  E0042   operand types are incompatible ("int" and "const char *")   Rock, Paper, Scissors   C:\Users\FULVIO\source\repos\Rock, Paper, Scissors\Rock, Paper, Scissors.cpp    29
Error (active)  E0042   operand types are incompatible ("int" and "const char *")   Rock, Paper, Scissors   C:\Users\FULVIO\source\repos\Rock, Paper, Scissors\Rock, Paper, Scissors.cpp    31
Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  Rock, Paper, Scissors   C:\Users\FULVIO\source\repos\Rock, Paper, Scissors\Rock, Paper, Scissors.cpp    36
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'PlayerUsername'    Rock, Paper, Scissors   c:\users\fulvio\source\repos\rock, paper, scissors\rock, paper, scissors.cpp    18
Error   C2059   syntax error: ';'   Rock, Paper, Scissors   c:\users\fulvio\source\repos\rock, paper, scissors\rock, paper, scissors.cpp    18
Error   C2446   '==': no conversion from 'const char *' to 'int'    Rock, Paper, Scissors   c:\users\fulvio\source\repos\rock, paper, scissors\rock, paper, scissors.cpp    21
Error   C2446   '==': no conversion from 'const char *' to 'int'    Rock, Paper, Scissors   c:\users\fulvio\source\repos\rock, paper, scissors\rock, paper, scissors.cpp    23
Error   C2446   '==': no conversion from 'const char *' to 'int'    Rock, Paper, Scissors   c:\users\fulvio\source\repos\rock, paper, scissors\rock, paper, scissors.cpp    25
Error   C2446   '==': no conversion from 'const char *' to 'int'    Rock, Paper, Scissors   c:\users\fulvio\source\repos\rock, paper, scissors\rock, paper, scissors.cpp    27
Error   C2446   '==': no conversion from 'const char *' to 'int'    Rock, Paper, Scissors   c:\users\fulvio\source\repos\rock, paper, scissors\rock, paper, scissors.cpp    29
Error   C2446   '==': no conversion from 'const char *' to 'int'    Rock, Paper, Scissors   c:\users\fulvio\source\repos\rock, paper, scissors\rock, paper, scissors.cpp    31
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'Playerinput'   Rock, Paper, Scissors   c:\users\fulvio\source\repos\rock, paper, scissors\rock, paper, scissors.cpp    37
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '}'    Rock, Paper, Scissors   c:\users\fulvio\source\repos\rock, paper, scissors\rock, paper, scissors.cpp    37

I would like to know: 
 * Why this code is not running.
 * How do I add a way to keep score on a text file.

Comment: You gave us instructions and your code, but what is your question? What do you have problem with?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're willing to help you, but we are not clairvoyant. Please take the time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54963503/edit) the question accordingly. Please create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and give sample inputs, outputs and the error messages you get, if any. This will help us to determine what is going on and improve your chances to get an answer.

Comment: Your code would be be easier to read if you formatted it in a more traditional manner, and more useful if it actually compiled. ` cin PlayerUsername >>;` and `cin Playerinput` are not valid code.

Comment: Fulvio, I'm guessing your code is not even compiling. If you even simply tell us that, we may be able to help. This is not a site primarily for homework help, but some of us may try to coach you if you give us the info we need.
You're new here, so please take comments as trying to be helpful.

Comment: It seems you have an error in the `cin` instruction try to modify it. and also, since you've declared the std namespace, you don't need to use it further the program.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome on stack overflow.

You could start to ask the player name using the right syntax:

```
cin >> PlayerUsername;
```

Then between the display of the instructions and the start of your chain of `if`/`else`, you should ask for the player input (rather than asking at the end) (and using the right syntax).

Then `RNG` is an `int`.  So you should compare it with integers and not strings literals (e.g.  `RND==1` and not `RND=="1"`).

A suggestion for improvement:  It would be nice before determining who wins, to display what the computer chose and what the user entered.  Because just the results give a sense of frustration, when it's not clear why one wins or loses.

Finally, for your future questions, it would be helpfull that you explain better your problem and the error message that you cannot understand (here a couple of syntax errors).